# Python pandas Removing UserWarning and looping efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

Lets say I have code similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'Name': [ 'Jay Leno', 'JayLin', 'Jay-Jameson', 'LinLeno', 'Lin Jameson', 'Python Leno', 'Python Lin', 'Python Jameson', 'Lin Jay', 'Python Monte'],
                 'Class': ['Rat','L','H','L','L','H', 'H','L','L','Circus']})
df['status']=''

pattern1=['^Jay(\s|-)?(Leno|Lin|Jameson)$','^Python(\s|-)?(Jay|Leno|Lin|Jameson|Monte)$','^Lin(\s|-)?(Leno|Jay|Jameson|Monte)$' ]
pattern2=['^Python(\s|-)?(Jay|Leno|Lin|Jameson|Monte)$' ]
pattern3=['^Lin(\s|-)?(Leno|Jay|Jameson|Monte)$' ]

for i in range(len(pattern1)):
    df.loc[df.Name.str.contains(pattern1[i]),'status'] = 'A'

for i in range(len(pattern2)):
    df.loc[df.Name.str.contains(pattern2[i]),'status'] = 'B'

for i in range(len(pattern3)):
    df.loc[df.Name.str.contains(pattern3[i]),'status'] = 'C'

print (df)
```

Which prints:

```
C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py:184: UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.
  " groups, use str.extract.", UserWarning)
    Class            Name status
0     Rat        Jay Leno      A
1       L          JayLin      A
2       H     Jay-Jameson      A
3       L         LinLeno      C
4       L     Lin Jameson      C
5       H     Python Leno      B
6       H      Python Lin      B
7       L  Python Jameson      B
8       L         Lin Jay      C
9  Circus    Python Monte      B

[10 rows x 3 columns]
```

My questions are how do I remove the error and Is there a way to loop through more efficiently with less code? I know there is something called list comprehensions but I am confused on how to use them.

I know the errors can be suppressed with

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [non-capturing parentheses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) `(?:...)`:

```
pattern1=['^Jay(?:\s|-)?(?:Leno|Lin|Jameson)$','^Python(?:\s|-)?(?:Jay|Leno|Lin|Jameson|Monte)$','^Lin(?:\s|-)?(?:Leno|Jay|Jameson|Monte)$' ]
pattern2=['^Python(?:\s|-)?(?:Jay|Leno|Lin|Jameson|Monte)$' ]
pattern3=['^Lin(?:\s|-)?(?:Leno|Jay|Jameson|Monte)$' ]
```

The warning comes from [this code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/strings.py#L182):

```
    if regex.groups > 0:
        warnings.warn("This pattern has match groups. To actually get the"
                      " groups, use str.extract.", UserWarning)
```

So as long as there are no groups, there is no warning.

Comment: I tried this on another set of code but got `Error: Nothing to repeat`

Comment: A runnable example which shows this error would be very helpful.

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it apparently you cannot have `(:??i)` and it must be `(?i)`

Comment: Funny how when faced with an error like this we search for ways to silence  the error vs fix it's cause.  I, for one, did!  @unutbu, thanks once again.  : )